# Normality testing with very large sample size?

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption

Hypothesis testing such as Anderson-Darling or Shapiro-Wilk's test check normality of a distribution. However, if the sample size is very large, the test is extremely "accurate" but practically useless because the confidence interval is too small. They will always reject the null, even if the distribution is reasonably normal enough.

How should I test normality when sample size is very large, other than visualizing histograms?

The motivation is that I want to automate checking normality of large data set in a software platform, where everything needs to be automated, not manually visualized and inspected by humans.

One thing that came across me is that instead of using Shapiro-Wilk test, I calculate kurtosis and skewness of the distribution, and if they are $\pm 1.0$, I can assume that my large dataset is "reasonably" normally distributed.

Is my approach correct, or is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Don't know about just looking at skewness and kurtosis.  Seems the main issue is to be realistic about what closeness to normality is needed for the application at hand.

Comment: What's your motivation to check normality in the first place? Why is normality important in your application?

Comment: Shapiro, not Saphiro. Hypothesis tests of assumptions answer the wrong question (e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)); when it comes to assumptions of tests, I suggest avoiding them at any sample size.

Comment: @Glen_b I came up with this question after reading the link you put. In the link, I read that hypothesis testing for normality in very large sample size is useless. My question is, how do I know that my distribution is normal "enough", and what technique i should use, other than visualizations? What techniques are realistic about measuring closeness to normality, as Bruce says?

Comment: 1. Please fix the spelling in your question as pointed out earlier. 2. Some of the answers at that other post go rather further. Indeed, I'd say that large sample sizes just make the uselessness *obvious*, but more generally it's not only not useful, it's actually often counterproductive (often leading you into doing exactly the wrong thing and at the same time screwing up the properties of your significance levels and p-values).

Comment: 3. I challenge the premise of the question -- given the problems with choosing analysis on the basis of what you find in the data, automated checking doesn't strike me as being as useful as building something that's more robust to violations of anything you can't reasonably assume.

Comment: You just, don't do it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Continuation from comment:  If you are using *simulated* normal data from R,
then you can be quite confident that what purport to be normal samples
really are. So there shouldn't be 'quirks' for the Shapio-Wilk test to detect.

Checking 100,000 standard normal samples of size 1000 with the Shapiro-Wilk
test, I got rejections just about 5% of the time, which is what one
would expect from a test at the 5% level.

```
set.seed(2019)
pv = replicate( 10^5, shapiro.test(rnorm(1000))$p.val )
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.05009
```

**Addendum.**
By contrast, the distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(20,20)$ "looks" very
much like a normal distribution, but isn't *exactly* normal.
If I do the same simulation for this approximate model, Shapiro-Wilk
rejects about 7% of the time. Looked at from the perspective of
power, that's not great. But it seems Shapiro-Wilk is sometimes
able to detect that the data aren't exactly normal.

This is a long
way from "always," but I think $\mathsf{Beta}(20,20)$ is closer
to normal than a lot of real-life "normal" data are. (And the link
says *always* may be "a bit strongly stated." I suspect the greatest
trouble may come with samples a lot bigger than 1000, and for some
normal approximations that are quite useful--even if imperfect.)
**"Not every statistically significant difference is a difference
of practical importance."** Sometimes, people who should know better seem to forget
that when doing goodness-of-fit tests.

```
set.seed(2019)
pv = replicate( 10^5, shapiro.test(rbeta(1000, 20,20))$p.val )
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.07152
```

[image]

Comment: you get that value because the 100,000 random samples you randomly generated are based on "perfect" normal distribution. If there is any extra noise to the random samples you generated, saphiro-wilk test will always reject the null, as shown in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless). And this is very relative to the real-life applications since no populations are perfectly normal

Comment: so, going back to the original question, how do I detect normal-enough nature of the distribution, even if its not perfectly normal? What method should I use to automate detecting near-normality without visually inspecting it?

Comment: First, you'd need to decide in quantitative terms what 'normal enough means. One idea. The $D$ stat in 1-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is max dif btw empirical CDF of the sample and CDF of normal. According to a fixed standard, use small enough $D$ as criterion, regardless of P-val. You'd have to check this idea out to see if it does what you really want--once you decide what that is.

Comment: All this discussion is completely moot without a clear definition of "normal enough" or "looks like normal" or "reasonably normal". A test makes only sense if it is clear what you are testing against. Distributions are objects with infinite degrees of freedom and each test can only fix one degree of freedom.
The OP needs to make up his mind what he requires from his "normal" samples and what deviations he expects or want to detect.

Comment: @BruceET I would use the following criteria: 1) Skewness close to 0, maybe a (-1,1) range, or that you feel more comfortable with depending on "how normal-like is normal enough". 2) Kurtosis close to 3 (or excess kurtosis close to 0) High kurtosis is often a greater issue than low kurtosis as it leads to more outliers

Answer (score 2):

As @gg pointed out in a comment, this entire discussion in pointless without defining how normal-like does data have to be for us to consider it "normal enough". In practice, I often like the following criteria:

- Skewness close to 0, maybe a (-1,1) range, or that you feel more comfortable with depending on "how normal-like is normal enough".
- Kurtosis close to 3 (or excess kurtosis close to 0) High kurtosis is often a greater issue than low kurtosis as it leads to more outliers.
- Median not far away from the mean
- QQ-plots are your friends!

Comment: Albeit, high kurtosis (counterintuitively) tends to lead to conservative tests, and low kurtosis to higher false positives (since variances tend to be overestimated in the former and underestimated in the latter).

Answer (score 0):

> ...However, if the sample size is very large, the test is extremely "accurate" but practically useless because the confidence interval is too small. They will always reject the null, even if the distribution is reasonably normal enough...

What if you take a sub-sample of size 100 or 300 from the large sample consisting of several thousands or more. If I'm not mistaken then taking the sub-samples will reflect the same distribution but will work better with the common normality tests.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Was this intended as an answer to the OP's question, 
a comment requesting clarification from the OP or one of the answerers, or a 
new question of your own? Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide 
answers to the original question. You will be able to comment anywhere when 
your reputation is >50. If you have a new question, click the blue `ASK QUESTION` 
at the top of the page & ask it there, then we can help you properly. Since you're 
new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.

Comment: It was intended as an answer.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. The solution to a significance test being hopeless for very large sample sizes because everything fails is not to find a different problem where significance tests sometimes don't fail.  It's better to wonder (1) how to plot and measure departure from normality rather than test for it (2) whether departure from normality matters for what else you intend to do.

Comment: Taking this advice to its logical conclusion -- since there's no basis for choosing 300 or 100 or even fewer elements in the subsample -- we might as well choose the minimum of 2, in which case any normality test will fail to reject the hypothesis.  If your objective is not to reject the hypothesis (as suggested by the question), then I suppose in that sense this "works better!"

Comment: Than what if a normal curve is fit on the histogram of the data with the same mean and sd and then sum the squared vertical differences and test a limit then? There would need to be a sophisticated method to try and find the best bin size for the histogram of the data as well.

Comment: Actually if a human can decide normality by looking at the histogram and we agree that this is the most reliable method, then I believe that a method could be constructed to do the same in algorithmic way. For instance fit the distribution of log normal, normal, exponential etc data with different parameters, that we could find using a gradient descent or other methods, Even training a statistical or machine learning model for it if there is enough time window for the task. And then an evaluation can be carried out after the best fit is found.